# How to use multi devise model for rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I have two devise models, `user` and `admin`, When `user` and `admin` login through login form, then will redirect to `/admin`

I have read the [rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Devise), but it seems just about configuration about single devise model, Can I define multi warden scope like following:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: [:user,:admin]
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
  config.current_admin_method(&:current_admin)
end
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing.  did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @eibrahim, No, I have to switch rails_admin to active_admin, it's more powerful

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one devise model. Here is an example (with a checksum authentication):

```
# initilizer/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.strategies.add :admin, Admin::ChecksumAuthenticatable
  end
end
```

You class `Admin::ChecksumAuthenticatable` (for example) needs to inherit from `::Devise::Strategies::Base`. Then define all methods you want and overwrite `authenticate!` method:

```
def authenticate!
  admin = Admin.from_checksum_for_auth!(checksum)
  # from_checksum_for_auth! is defined on Admin model and check checksum validity
  success! admin
end
```